# Why would an oil separator have a vent into the engine bay?

Tags: pcv-valve

This is Alfa Romeo Giulietta installed oil separator. Disassembly shows the vent is guarded by a flat rubber circle pushed up by a spring. This rubber flab probably ensures the air only flows in. Other than that the separator is connected to the engine block for oil to drip, and has two hoses: one leading to the intake hose before turbo charger and the other probably to the crank case. Why would it have this vent in the cover?

[image: oil separator]

Answer (score 0):

If the cover did not have a vent, then the membrane could only move if it compressed the air enclosed or caused a depression relative to atmospheric pressure which is not the effect the desingner / manufacturer was wanting...

Comment: Sorry, I think I misnamed the thing. It is not really a membrane in the sense that it filters things, it is a large flat rubber sort of gasket that ensure the air can only come in not out. I don't think it is there to separate the oil. I'll edit the question.

Comment: A membrane does not have to be a filter... It may just be there to stop dirt ingress...

Comment: Still don't understand your answer. The air is supposed to flow from the crank case through the separator into the intake. What is the vent for?